# Which unit test will force to write the next asynchronous C# code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, tdd

On this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563299/how-to-call-any-method-asynchronously-in-c-sharp), a recommendation is made on how to write a async method in c#, which is:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
void Foo(){}
...
new Task(Foo).Start();
```

My question is about how to apply a TDD approach to that code, exactly: which unit test I should write to force the writing of the previous code.

Thanks :)

Comment: Asynchronous method(especially methods which access external resources) should be written so that you can consume it like: `await Foo()` without manually starting tasks.

Comment: For forcing to write asynchronous function just assert that return value is of type `Task` or `Task<T>`

Comment: Thats an old question/answer, (just) before async/await was available

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to ask yourself what you're actually testing? In the example you provided:

```
void Foo(){}
```

Foo is just a method on class so you would create a test that tests the functionality of Foo and it has nothing to do with writing tests for async code.

However if Foo had a return type of `Task` or `Task<T>` you could do the following.

Given the class:

```
public class Bar
{
    public Task<string> Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo called");
        return Task.FromResult("123");
    }
}
```

The test would then look like:

```
[TestClass]
public class BarTest
{

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Test_Foo()
    {
        // Arrange
        var bar = new Bar();

        // Act
        var result = await bar.Foo();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("123", result);
    }
}
```