# How to call any c# code( function, web reference, API call) asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have tried looking into the [How to call any method asynchronously in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563299/how-to-call-any-method-asynchronously-in-c-sharp) question but it fails to answer by query so let me ask it anyway.

I am accessing a web refence in my code which basically calls a function called ExportDataset.

```
DataSet dsUsers = serviceOws.ExportDatasetAsync("test012", "<parameters></parameters>");
```

The problem with this bit is it takes about 30 seconds to fetch the records. I cannot change the web reference code at all as i dont have access. My page doesn't load at all whilst this happens.

Is there any way to call this function asyncrounously whilst my page loads? My project targets .NET framework 4.6.1

Comment: Your... . page?

Comment: What page? Where does that code run? What framework? We need much more details.

Comment: yes, webpage if you want to get down to brass tacks

Comment: Assuming you're talking about a web app, you cannot return the response until all your async operations are complete unless you fire-and-forget which would be pointless in your case. You could code the page to do a client-side ajax request. You'd have to provide another endpoint to do the actual service call because obviously you can't use the service reference in the client browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap synchronous calls in a `Task` by using `Task t = new Task(() => MyLongRunningOperation())`, but that won't get your page rendering faster because it's still going to wait for that task to finish before sending the page content. You will need to expose this call in a separate API or something else and load it via AJAX if you really want a long running operation like this to work "seamlessley".

Comment: thanks. Yeah. I guess i will have to use AJAX. Just thought there might be a smarter way of doing it. Thanks for you help. Points me in the right direction. Definitely much more helpful than smart ass comments from keyboard warriors

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a framework that can automagically tie up an asynchronous operation *render* asynchronously as well on the client side.