# How to make an existing code block async in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I have an existing code block with Linq to SQL queries and HTTP requests, that I'd like to make async for the purpose of using less threads.

Will it suffice to put the code block in an async method, like so?

```
    public async Task<Customer> ProcessACustomer()
    {
        return await GetCustomer();
    }

    public Task<Customer> GetCustomer()
    {
        // Linq to SQL query here

        // HTTP request here

        Customer customer;
        return Task.FromResult<Customer>(customer);
    }
```

...or do I have to make every piece of logic in `GetCustomer()` async to accomplish this?

My hurdle here is that I have a ton of logic in that method (oversimplified above), so time will be an issue. Also, I can't seem to convert my Linq To SQL queries to async, as the async extension methods are not available for some reason (System.Data.Linq.Table does not contain a definition for FirstOrDefaultAsync() f.ex.).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call any method asynchronously in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563299/how-to-call-any-method-asynchronously-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If the operations are not implemented as pure asynchronous IO then you will not be saving any threads by offloading work to another task. What is your rationale for wanting to "using less threads"? Do you need to keep a user interface responsive during the operation(s)?

Comment: @Crowcoder it's not for responsiveness, but for scalability: this method spends a lot of time waiting, and it gets called a lot. My theory is that all the threads this creates generates unnecessary overhead.

Comment: "Go async all the way" ... So, whatever _can_ be called async, do so.

Comment: @gunr2171 As I see it, async and await solves the problem of a thread being blocked while waiting; Task.Run would just move it to a different thread that then gets blocked. Is this incorrect?

Comment: OK, then you won't gain scalability by forcing something into an async task that is not inherently async. You could push the operation out to another service (queue/serverless function, etc. ) to shift the burden if it really is that critical. Or you can refactor to not use a synchronous api like LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder - I'll mark this as the answer if you post it as such.

Comment: Do your http calls / results and SQL results depend on each other? Like for example do you need some id from http to query sql? Or are they completely independent and you just combine results at the very end?

Comment: @Fildor they depend on each other unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will it suffice to put the code block in an async method, like so?

No. The `GetCustomer` method is not asynchronous. It synchronously performs its work  and then returns a completed task. This will not save any threads.

> do I have to make every piece of logic in GetCustomer() async to accomplish this?

If you want to convert to `async`, then you should start at the opposite end. Don't start with the goal of making `ProcessACustomer` (or `GetCustomer`) asynchronous. Instead, start with the lowest-level API. Whatever your db access method is, make *that* asynchronous first and then let the `async` grow out from there.

> My hurdle here is that I have a ton of logic in that method (oversimplified above), so time will be an issue.

This is a classic tradeoff. It may be worthwhile to convert to `async`, or it may be worthwhile to buy a few more servers instead.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this is exactly what I needed to know.